# How to pass a new variable to python script using 'for' loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, program-entry-point

I am trying to write a python script that will traverse through a list and then pass a new variable to an other python script. Here is my code:

## Script: ENCViewer.py

```
 # import necessary modules
 import os

 # list of all ENCS
 root = os.listdir('/home/cassandra/desktop/file_formats/ENC_ROOT')
 root.sort()
 root = root[2:]

 for ENC in root:
      # pass new instance of variable 'ENC' to ENCReader.py
     import ENCReader.py
```

## Script: ENCReader.py

```
from __main__ import *
print ENC
.... # remaining script
```

Currently, when executing the first code, ENCViewer.py, it will only execute once then exit. How can I pass new instance variables of 'ENC' to ENCReader.py so that it executes throughout the entire 'for' loop seen in the first snippet of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "other python script" you mean another process?  If so then you need some form of Inter-Process Communication, like a pipe, a socket, or a message queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if what you are asking is possible, but I think that you miss understood the idea of creating modules and importing code. The "standard" way of achieving the same result is the following:

ENCReader.py

```
def printer(var):
    print(var)
    # your code..
```

ENCViewer.py

```
 import os
 from ENCReader import printer

 # list of all ENCS
 root = os.listdir('/home/cassandra/desktop/file_formats/ENC_ROOT')
 root.sort()
 root = root[2:]

for ENC in root:
    printer(ENC)
```

Comment: I think you mean ENC?